# Docker image is not running after copying custom nginx config

Tags: nginx, docker

I have a **`DockerFile`** below

```
FROM node:latest AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i && npm run prod_build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ["nginx.conf", "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"]
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now the custom nginx config file **`nginx.conf`** is below

```
user                            root;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    listen       80;
    server_name  10.168.8.59;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Docker build works fine but after running the docker run command if I run `docker ps` it shows nothing. Commands are below

```
docker build -t po .
docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 po

docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: And the error log shows .... what?

Comment: I am really new to these things. It did not give me any error. Where can I find the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
docker ps -a
```

And you will see all your containers, copy the CONTAINER ID and run:

```
docker logs CONTAINER ID
```